# Prove that the equation $\tan (z)=z$ has only real roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the equation $\tan(z)=z$ has only real roots. How to do it?
The idea is that the increment of the argument need to look at the boundary of the square with a side of $\pi n$ and another that $\tan(z)-z$ has a pole at $0$. I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I think your question is attracting downvotes because it's unclear what it is that you're asking. In addition, many users would expect you to include some indication of what you've tried so far to solve the problem, even a simple "I don't know where to start" would be better than nothing!

Comment: @Tom Oldfield ,Ok)I edited)

Comment: One method makes use of Rouche's theorem. Consider the functions $g(z) = z$ and $h(z) = -\tan z$ and the rectangle with vertices $\pm \pi \; \pm \; \pi i.$

Comment: and what should I do after?...because I can`t solve it exactly( @Dave L.Renfro

Comment: If you must use Rouche's theorem, you can find it worked out on pp. 255-256 of Volume 1 of Einar Hille's text **Analytic Function Theory** (1973).

Answer (score 13):

Suppose $\tan(x+iy)=x+iy$. Use the expansion $\tan(x+iy)=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x+\cosh2y}+i\frac{\sinh 2y}{\cos 2x+\cosh 2y}$ to get: $$\frac{1}{\cos2x+\cosh2y}(\sin2x+i \sinh2y)=x+iy .$$

This means that the 2 vectors $(\sin2x,\sinh2y)$ and $(x,y)$ are proportional, and therefore the determinant of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x & y \\ \sin2x &\sinh2y \end{pmatrix}=0$.

We get $x \sinh2y=y \sin2x$. Using the well-known inequalities $$|\sin t| \leq |t|,|\sinh t| \geq |t|$$ we see that we must have $x=0$ or $y=0$ (this is true because equality holds in the inequalities above iff $t=0$).

The case $y=0$ gives the wanted real solutions, and a small calculation shows that the case $x=0$ gives the one-and-only imaginary solution, namely $z=0$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Consider [Rouchet's Theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Rouch%C3%A9) for **meromorphic** functions:

- $f$, $g$ are meromorphic in open connected $G \subset \overline{\mathbb{C}}$
- $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ on $\partial G$.

Then $$Z_{f+g} - P_{f + g} = Z_{f} - P_{f}$$ where $Z_h$, $P_h$ denote the number of zeroes and poles of $h$ inside $G$ counted with multiplicieties.

2. Now  consider two functions, $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=-\tan(z)$ on the circle $|z|=\pi n$.

As we know, $\tan(z)$ [is bounded outside the](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269600/function-tanz-is-bounded-for-all-epsilon0-outside-of-epsilon-neighbo)  $\epsilon$-neighborhood of its poles $\pi/2 + \pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Choose $M$ s.t. the inequality $M\ge |\tan(z)|$ holds outside the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\pi/2 + \pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

On the circle $|z|=\pi n$ for large enough $n$ we have:

$$
|z| = \pi n > M \ge |\tan(z)|
$$

since $|\pi n - (\pi/2 + \pi k)| \ge \epsilon$. (Just choose $\epsilon < \pi/2$ and adjust the corresponding $M$).

3. By Rouchet's Theorem for meromorphic functions:

$$
Z_{z-\tan(z)} - P_{z-\tan(z)} = Z_{z} - P_{z} \\
\implies Z_{z-\tan(z)} = P_{z-\tan(z)} + Z_{z} - P_{z} = 2n + 1 - 0 = 2n + 1
$$

which is exactly the number of real roots of the equation $\tan(x)=x$ on $x \in (-\pi n, \pi n)$:

- 3 roots on interval $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$
- 1 root on each interval $ x \in (-\pi k + \pi/2, -\pi (k-1) + \pi /2)$, $k=1, 2, 3, ..., n$
- 1 root on each interval $x \in (\pi/2 + \pi k, \pi /2 + \pi k)$, $k=0, 1, 2, 3,..., n-1$

Comment: Could you please give a reference for the version of this theorem that involves poles? Also didn’t you forget absolute values in the inequality?

Comment: @Vladislav I've added reference to wiki. It seems this version of the theorem is actually a "rare" one. When I was taking CA class, everybody seems to implicitly use it, but nobody told it was applicable to meromorphic. It should be much more popular. *At least* as the common formulation.