How many roots does $\tan(z)-z^n$ have for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le \Re(z)\le \frac{\pi}{2}$?
Now asked on MO here.

I am investigating the number of roots of the equation
$$\tan(z) - z^n = 0$$
within the vertical strip $|\text{Re}(z)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for positive integers $n$. Numerical computations suggest interesting behavior:

The equation $\tan(z) - z = 0$ has only the trivial solution $z = 0$.
For $n \ge 2$, the number of roots appears to depend on the value of $n$. Plots for some cases are shown below:

$\tan(z)-z$:

$\tan(z)-z^2$ (showing 3 roots):

$\tan(z)-z^3$ (showing 5 roots):

$\tan(z)-z^4$ (showing 5 roots):

$\tan(z)-z^{11}$ (showing 11 roots):

$\tan(z)-z^{12}$ (showing 12 roots):


I used this python code:

import cplot
import numpy as np
print("enter  n  ")
n= int(input())

def f(z):
    res =np.tan(z)-z**n
    return res

plt = cplot.plot(f, (-1.6, +1.6, 1000), (-1.6, +1.6, 1000))
plt.show()


Define $a_n$ to be the number of roots that $\tan(z)-z^n$ have for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le \Re(z)\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, The question is how to find $a_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
The first few values are $1,3,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16$, it seems that for $n\ge5, \ a_n=n$ but I couldn't explain this behaviour or if it is true for all $n\ge5$.

In contrast to $\tan(z) - z^n$, the equations $\sin(z) - z^n = 0$ and $\cos(z) - z^n = 0$ always have exactly $n$ roots in the strip $|\text{Re}(z)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
Also the equations $\cot(z) - z^n = 0$ and $\csc(z) - z^n = 0$ always have exactly $n+1$ roots in the strip $|\text{Re}(z)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, However the equations $\sec(z) - z^n = 0$ is like the equation  $\tan(z)-z^n$  i.e (have   $n$ roots in the strip $|\text{Re}(z)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $ n \ge 5$) .
How to explain this behavior?

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4453232/1188598 This answer might be helpful

A plot with some larger odd $n$ would be interesting, e.g. $n=11$. – Can you tell which software you used to produce the plots?

@MartinR I am using python I will put my code in both questions and plot when $n=11$

@MartinR I added the plot of $n=11$

@MartinR Can you explain why when $n=2,3,4$, $a_n\ne n$, why exactly $a_n=n$ starts when $n ge 5$ ?

My guess is that it is because $n=5$ is the smallest value for which $\tan(x) =x^n$ has solutions in the real interval $(0, \pi/2)$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What about the seemingly easier number of solutions of $\sin{z}=z^n$? If I’m not mistaken, a direct application of the argument principle expresses this number as an integral to compute, but it looks rather involved, and I can’t currently see a good way to apply Rouché…

The question has been answered on MO – is this question still needed here?

@MartinR I don't know but I think cross posts shouldn't be deleted, if so I have to delete a lot of questions...

You can also post a summary of the MO solution here (with a link to the MO answer) and mark it as accepted.
